# Retrieve field from generic

Tags: c#, generics

I am trying to strongly type model validation exceptions. I have an generic exception class that takes an expression as a parameter. I need to catch that generic exception and retrieve the field name from the expression. Problem is since its a generic, it's not straightforward.

FieldValidationException.cs:

```
public class FieldValidationException<TModel> : Exception where TModel : class {
    public Expression<Func<TModel, object>> Field { get; }

    public FieldValidationException(string message, Expression<Func<TModel, object>> field) : base(message) {
        Field = field;
    }
}
```

MyModelValidator.cs:

```
try {
    throw new FieldValidationException<MyModel>("Error", model => model.userId)
} catch (Exception ex) {
    if (ex.GetType().GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(FieldValidationException<>)) {
        Expression<Func<object, object>> field = ??? //How do I retrieve the field?
        fieldName = expression.Member.Name;
        Debug.WriteLine(fieldName);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why did you construct the exception such that everything is statically typed if you want to use it in a context where the type is not statically known?  If you want to be able to use it in a non-statically typed way, design the type so that everything isn't statically typed.

Comment: You´d have to `catch (FieldValidationException<MyModel>)`. There´s no other way to refer to a compile-time type than providing it at compile-time. Providing it at runtime will just give you the non-generc base-class `Exception` with which you can´t do much.

Comment: @Servy Because this allows to not hard code property name as strings everywhere I throw the exception (we're talking about thousands of model validation exceptions that are thrown). Doing this provides compile-time checking of the field names. This is what we currently have and it is just very error-prone: `throw new FieldValidationException<MyModel>("Error", "userId")`

Comment: Passing the property name via the `nameof` operator would eliminate all (performance unfriendly) reflection and would give the same compiletime safety.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by doing the retrieval of the field name from member expression within the `FieldValidationException` instead of the catching class.

FieldValidationException.cs:

```
public class FieldValidationException<TModel> : Exception where TModel : class {
    public string FieldName { get; }

    public FieldValidationException(string message, Expression<Func<TModel, object>> field) : base(message) {
        FieldName = (MemberExpression)field.Body.Member.Name;
    }
}
```

Then, I can get the field name using reflection:

MyModelValidator.cs:

```
if (ex.GetType().GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(FieldValidationException<>)) {
    PropertyInfo fieldNameProperty = ex.GetType().GetProperty("FieldName");
    var fieldName = fieldNameProperty.GetValue(ex) as string; 
}
```